# How to populate my SQLitedatabase from a external file?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I created my database in my android application, but now I have to pre-populate it with some data. The problem is that it have a lot of data to put in the database. Is there some way to pre-populate the database from a file .txt or from a external file .db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach data to your application (or download it from www) just as scv files, then parse them and insert in OnCreate method of your db helper.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        // create database file
        database.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

        // load data
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        try {
                InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("radars_test.csv");
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String line;
                String[] values;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        values = line.split(";");
                        String speedLimit = (line.length() == 3 ? values[2] : "0");
                        String insertCommand = String
                                        .format("insert into geofences(longitude, latitude, speed_limit, type, radius, description) values(\"%s\", \"%s\", %s, 0, 200, \"%s\")",
                                                        values[0], values[1], speedLimit, values[3]);
                        database.execSQL(insertCommand);

                }

        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TBCAE", "Failed to open data input file");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

.csv file must be placed in assets directory

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Looks like it will work. Was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I did not understand the code. First of all, in witch format the csv has to be? It has to be: "INSERT INTO tb_marcas (id_marca marca id_especie_fk) VALUES (1 Acura' 1);"

Comment: I did not understand the code. First of all, in witch format the csv file has to be formated? only the data or inserts? My Table is like that: "CREATE TABLE car_brand (id integer, brand text)".

Comment: Sorry piotrpo but I did not understand the code. I did not understand the insert part and the speedLimit variable. My csv file has 2 colums, where should I change the code?

Comment: Can you help me piotrpo?

Comment: Ok, this code is just from working application and this db should contains data about speed cameras, so "speed_limit" is just speed limit in the particular area :) insert is also easy - it works with standard SQL command - look at SQLite documentation to get help with it. CSV format is just CSV format - value0,value1,value2 each line is one record for this table .split() command parses each line

Comment: Ok, now I did understand. Bus its retorning a error. My code is: ...... String marcas = values[0];                                            long id = Long.parseLong(values[1]);                           String insertCommand = "INSERT INTO tb_marca VALUES ("  + marcas + ", " + id + ");"; "  And is retourning a error : Failure 1 (no such column: Acura) on 0x1efab0 when preparing 'INSERT INTO tb_marca VALUES (Acura, 1);'.

Comment: I did It now, thank you very much. The error was in my SQL statement. Now its ok. Thank you very much. Sorry for being annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what format you actually have but yes, very possible. Use a destkop SQLite editor and import a CSV file (for example).  Most SQLite editors support this.

Then simply copy the .db3 file to your project.

I use this one:

http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Also, read this http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Where in my project I can copy the .db file?

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Great post here. I had it bookmarked for a long time.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I think it will answer all your problems.

Comment: It's not a best approach. SQLite versions can differ between android devices, so compatibility isssues can occur.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create the database on your own using a manager like [SQLite Manager for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). This manager lets you import Excel files (that are actually CSV) with the data to the database. After that you should store your database in the raw folder of your application. Then, you should create a DataAdapter to retrieve the data using cursors. If you want more details, don't hesitate to ask. Good luck.